# Как заполнить Entry подсказкой?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Например выводить текст 'Логин' не в Label перед Entry, а непосредственно отображать 'Логин' в поле Entry. При вводе подсказка (текст 'Логин') исчезает.

Например, как в поле указания заголовка вопроса на Stackoverflow:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая связь между вопросом и картинкой?

Comment: Это скрин для примера

Comment: Убедительный пример. Но лучше бы вопрос сформулировать, чтобы было понятно без картинки.

Answer (score 1):

Это называется placeholder, и по умолчанию Entry его не поддерживает. Но это можно исправить:

```
import tkinter as tk

class EntryWithPlaceholder(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, placeholder=None):
        super().__init__(master)

        if placeholder is not None:
            self.placeholder = placeholder
            self.placeholder_color = 'grey'
            self.default_fg_color = self['fg']

            self.bind("<FocusIn>", self.focus_in)
            self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.focus_out)

            self.put_placeholder()

    def put_placeholder(self):
        self.insert(0, self.placeholder)
        self['fg'] = self.placeholder_color

    def focus_in(self, *args):
        if self['fg'] == self.placeholder_color:
            self.delete('0', 'end')
            self['fg'] = self.default_fg_color

    def focus_out(self, *args):
        if not self.get():
            self.put_placeholder()


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    root = tk.Tk()

    username = EntryWithPlaceholder(root, 'Логин')
    password = EntryWithPlaceholder(root, 'Пароль')

    username.pack()
    password.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

<sub>Код основан на коде из [ответа на вопрос «How to add placeholder to an Entry in tkinter?»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47928390) от участника  [@Nae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7032856).</sub>

Comment: если вы [копируете код один в один](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47928390/4279), то указывайте источник.

Comment: @jfs не надоело ещё заниматься преследованием? Я наверняка скопировал этот код откуда-то, но [точно не из ответа](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkETE.png) по вашей ссылке.

Comment: @jfs я утверждаю, что не помню откуда я его взял. Возможно, у этого же автора ранее где-то в другом месте. Возможно, у нас с ним был один источник. Возможно, и для такого простого кода вероятно, это просто совпадение.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74309/discussion-on-answer-by-sergey-gornostaev---entry-).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, вы не будете против, если я добавлю ссылку на источник из комментария в сам вопрос (или вы сами его добавите)? Я **не** утверждаю, что вы копировали код именно из того ответа, но фактически код совпадает с точностью до одного if и пустых строк (ну и переведенных "Логин" и "Пароль"). Почему это желательно сделать см.: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10211

Comment: Либо, если есть какой-то другой первоисточник кода (и в этом ответе, и в ответе на enSO), то добавить его и здесь, и там.

Comment: @insolor не буду против.

Answer (score 1):

Пример, как сделать чтобы подсказка появлялась, если текстовое поле пустое, пропадала когда начинаем печатать:

```
import tkinter as tk


class EntryWithPlaceholder(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, placeholder=None):
        self.entry_var = tk.StringVar()
        super().__init__(master, textvariable=self.entry_var)

        if placeholder is not None:
            self.placeholder = placeholder
            self.placeholder_color = 'grey'
            self.default_fg_color = self['fg']
            self.placeholder_on = False
            self.put_placeholder()

            self.entry_var.trace("w", self.entry_change)

            # При всех перечисленных событиях, если placeholder отображается, ставить курсор на 0 позицию
            self.bind("<FocusIn>", self.reset_cursor)
            self.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.reset_cursor)
            self.bind("<ButtonRelease>", self.reset_cursor)

    def entry_change(self, *args):
        if not self.get():
            self.put_placeholder()
        elif self.placeholder_on:
            self.remove_placeholder()
            self.entry_change()  # На случай, если после удаления placeholder остается пустое поле

    def put_placeholder(self):
        self.insert(0, self.placeholder)
        self['fg'] = self.placeholder_color
        self.icursor(0)
        self.placeholder_on = True

    def remove_placeholder(self):
        # Если был вставлен какой-то символ в начало, удаляем не весь текст, а только placeholder:
        text = self.get()[:-len(self.placeholder)]
        self.delete('0', 'end')
        self['fg'] = self.default_fg_color
        self.insert(0, text)
        self.placeholder_on = False

    def reset_cursor(self, *args):
        if self.placeholder_on:
            self.icursor(0)


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    root = tk.Tk()

    entry = EntryWithPlaceholder(root, 'Some Text')
    entry.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

По хорошему еще нужно убрать возможность выделить текст placeholder'а (при двойном клике или при нажатии shift-вправо), но мне лень это реализовывать)

Answer (score -1):

Пример

```
enter_name = ttk.Entry(popup, width=20, font=("Arial", 12))
enter_name.insert(0, "Текст по умолчанию")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Вопрос не про текст по умолчанию, а текст подсказки в поле ввода. См. первый абзац в вопросе: `Например выводить текст 'Логин' не в Label перед Entry, а непосредственно отображать 'Логин' в поле Entry. При вводе подсказка (текст 'Логин') исчезает.` У вас текст "подсказки" при вводе никуда не исчезает.